# Using Row_Number() with Update Statement

Tags: postgresql

Hopefully just a quick question. I am having some difficulty wrapping my mind around to using row_number() on UPDATE statement.

Assuming i have a bookshelf table:

```
userid  createddate bookid  pagenumber
1       2021-18-01  charper    141
1       2021-17-01  mproust    136
1       2021-17-01  sking       134
1       2021-15-01  charper    128
1       2021-10-01  jausten    122
2       2021-18-01  vwoolf    141
2       2021-17-01  vwoolf    136
2       2021-17-01  charper    134
```

I want to (sum) same bookid pagenumber and write to right column. My expect result must be like:

```
userid  createddate      bookid pagenumber  countrow
1         2021-18-01    charper  141        269
1         2021-17-01    mproust  136        136
1         2021-17-01    sking    134        134
1         2021-15-01    charper  128        
1         2021-11-01    jausten  122        122
2         2021-18-01    vwoolf   141        277
2         2021-17-01    vwoolf   136        
2         2021-17-01    charper  134        134
```

My SELECT Statement

```
SELECT userid, bookid, pagenumber,
       case when row_number() over (partition by userid, bookid order by bookid) = 1 
            then sum(pagenumber) over (partition by userid, bookid) 
       end as countrow
  from usertable;
```

Above sql query is works very well to show countrow on temp column. I want to store all those outputs. So i changed to statement like:

```
UPDATE bookshelf
SET countrow = countrow_new
FROM ( select userid, createddate, bookid, pagenumber,
       case when row_number() over (partition by userid, bookid, order by bookid) = 1
            then sum(pagenumber) over (partition by userid, bookid) 
       end as countrow_new
  from bookshelf
      )x
```

This query seems not working properly. Its update the all cells in countrow with wrong values. I'd search across to google and found something useful like [SqlHack Rowcount](https://www.sqlshack.com/working-with-sql-server-rowcount/) and [SqlServer Reference Page](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/) but nothing much. Does anyone have any idea what is going on here or has anyone had a similar issue ?
How can fix this to get expected result?

Comment: Based on the references in your question, I added the SQL Server tag.  Please tag questions with the database you are using.

Comment: SQL Server or Postgres? They are very different when it comes to UPDATEs with a FROM clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update a column (`countrow`) that doesn't exist in your table so you will need to add this column to your original table and join to the subquery:

```
/* add the column */
ALTER TABLE usertable ADD countrow INT;

/* do the update */
UPDATE  usertable
SET     countrow = countrow_new
FROM ( 
        SELECT  userid, 
                createddate, 
                bookid, 
                pagenumber,
                CASE 
                    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, bookid ORDER BY bookid) = 1
                    THEN SUM(pagenumber) OVER (PARTITION BY userid, bookid) 
                END AS countrow_new
        FROM    usertable
      ) x
      JOIN usertable u
        ON u.bookid = x.bookid AND u.createddate = x.createddate AND u.userid = x.userid;
```

The above assumes `{bookid,createddate,userid}` will always be unique

**However**, storing calculations in a table this way is very bad design and bad practice - you will have to keep the column up to date with a trigger on every insert / update / delete which will be terrible for performance.

A better approach would be to take your original query and create a view for it which can then be used as though it was a table:

create the view:

```
CREATE VIEW vwMyView
AS
SELECT  userid, 
        bookid, 
        pagenumber,
        CASE 
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, bookid ORDER BY bookid) = 1 
            THEN SUM(pagenumber) OVER (PARTITION BY userid, bookid) 
        END AS countrow
FROM    usertable;
```

Select from the view:

```
SELECT * FROM vwMyView;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have not tested this but I think you need to do an update join. I think you might need the extra filter - RN - to only update the latest bookid record.

```
WITH latestreadtotal AS
(
         SELECT   userid,
                  createddate,
                  bookid,
                  pagenumber,
                  row_number() OVER (partition BY userid, bookid order by bookid) AS rn,
                  CASE
                           WHEN row_number() OVER (partition BY userid, bookid, ORDER BY bookid) = 1 THEN sum(pagenumber) OVER (partition BY userid, bookid)
                  END AS countrow_new
         FROM     bookshelf )
UPDATE bsf
FROM   bookshelf bsf
JOIN   latestreadtotal lrt
ON     bsf.userid = lrt.userid
AND    bsf.createddate = lrt.createddate
AND    bsf.bookid = lrt.bookid
AND    bsf.pagenumber = lrt.pagenumber
AND    lrt.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to change the `update` to `x`:

```
UPDATE x
    SET countrow = countrow_new
    FROM (select userid, createddate, bookid, pagenumber,
                 (case when row_number() over (partition by userid, bookid, order by bookid) = 1
                       then sum(pagenumber) over (partition by userid, bookid) 
                  end )as countrow_new
          from bookshelf
         ) x;
```

Your code references `bookshelf` *in the subquery*.  However, the result is called `x`.  That probably means that the `bookshelf` in the `update` counts as a separate reference.  I must admit that SQL Server has arcane rules about table resolving table references in `update`s.  I usually just use a CTE for such single-table transformtions:

```
WITH toupdate AS (
      select userid, createddate, bookid, pagenumber,
             (case when row_number() over (partition by userid, bookid, order by bookid) = 1
                   then sum(pagenumber) over (partition by userid, bookid) 
              end )as countrow_new
      from bookshelf
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET countrow = countrow_new;
```